# How to use the image_tag with bootstrap class: "img-responsive" ? Chapter 11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

The reason I’m asking the question is to get some help me with a really annoying syntax error. I'm using chapter 11 so I can build a blog section on my new site with images, everything is working apart from when i try to add class: "img-responsive" to this line.

```
<%= image_tag image_article.picture.url if image_article.picture? %>
```

I just can't figure out the correct syntax to add class: "img-responsive".

The image is uploading fine but it breaks out of the col-md-6 container, and displays the full image breaking the page-layout, so it's all working locally apart from when I try to add class: “img-responsive” in parentheses or brackets, every way I try crashes the app, so I’m stuck. I've looked around for other solutions, i've found a gem that works with carrierwave ...

[responsive-images gem](https://github.com/johnkoht/responsive-images/)

but this seems to be like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, so far all the other problems i've had i've figured out, but this is really annoying. I can't find anything with carrierwave resizing that fits the bill for responsive images, surely i can use the img-responsive class?

Regards
Shaun

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to give the tag inside brackets

```
<%=image_tag(image_article.picture.url, class: "img-responsive") if image_article.picture?%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nope, it still breaks out of the col-md-6 container.

Comment: when you check with inspect element from your browser is it displaying the class="img-responsive" ?

Comment: It's funny you should ask that question because i was just looking at that. No, class="img-responsive" isn't showing. Having said that, the responsive layout is all working on the site, but the class isn't being applied, which is odd.

Comment: I'm really not sure what difference it made, but I just restarted the server and now it's all working. So, all I needed to do was put the tag inside brackets as suggested.

    <%=image_tag(image_article.picture.url, class: "img-responsive") if image_article.picture?%>

Restart the server, and bingo. Happy Days. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap 4 uses class: 'img-fluid' instead of 'img-responsive'

Try:

```
<%= image_tag image_article.picture.url, class: 'img-fluid' if image_article.picture? %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..it worked for me.. 
in  place of xyz.png, add the image name as in Assets folder.

**<%= image_tag("xyz.png", class: "img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle") %>**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<%= image_tag image_article.picture.url, class: "img-responsive" if image_article.picture? %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I did try that and it didn't work :( The app doesn't crash with this, but it still breaks out of the col-md-6 container, displays the full image breaking the page-layout.

Comment: You can provide a bootstrap class if 'img-responsive' does not work and you want to put it under some specific container. Like: <%= image_tag image_article.picture.url, class: "img-responsive col-md-6" if image_article.picture? %>

Comment: Thanks for that, still nothing.

Comment: Can you see these classes on this element via inspect element ?

Comment: <img src="/uploads/image_article/picture/11/Anna-_MirjaGeh_123.jpg" alt="Anna  mirjageh 123" /> It looks like its just being ignored

Comment: Thanks for your help, it needed the tag inside brackets, and a server re-start, job done.