# How to display image from rails local project folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, twitter-bootstrap

Very basic question, but somehow I can't get it to work. I am trying to have an image located in project's local folder to display on Rails. Additionally, I am using bootstrap; thus I need to declare `class: "img-responsive"` as well. Here is the original code: `<img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/mockup/img2.jpg" alt="">`

I have consulted [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368682/how-to-use-the-image-tag-with-bootstrap-class-img-responsive-chapter-11) which suggested `<%= image_tag("xyz.png", class: "img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle") %>` and [rubyonrails guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html) which suggested `image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", class: "menu_icon")`.

I have tried

```
<%= image_tag ("assets/img/mockup/img2.jpg", class: "img-responsive")%>
```

and

```
<%= image_tag "assets/img/mockup/img2.jpg" %>
```

But it still does not work.
I can confirm that the path is: `app/assets/img/mockup/img2.jpg`

How can I display the said image on rails app view?

Comment: try the answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665593/rails-paperclip-default-url-not-working/38666247#38666247

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was browsing and saw [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827763/why-images-are-not-showing-in-my-rails-basic-app).
I was able to get it work using

```
<%= image_tag ("/assets/mockup/img2.jpg"), class: "img-responsive"%>
```

Image path was `assets/images/mockup/img2.jpg`; omitting `images` from the image path `assets/mockup/img2.jpg` solves the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

1) Move your `img` folder contents to `app/assets/images` and then reference the image like:

```
<%= image_tag ("mockup/img2.jpg", class: "img-responsive")%>
```

2) Add your `img` folder to the Rails assets path search in the file `config/application.rb`

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "img")
```

This happens because `app/assets/img/` is not included by default in the rails assets search path.

For more info check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Comment: I went to change the `img` to `images` and did `<%= image_tag "/mockup/img2.jpg"%>` as suggested on the link; the website loads but the image does not show. `<%= image_tag ("/mockup/img2.jpg", class: "img-responsive") %>` gives syntax error. `<%= image_tag ("/mockup/img2.jpg"), class: "img-responsive"%>` loads the page with no error, but the image still does not load.

Comment: Solved it. Found my own solution. However, I appreciate the help! I learned something new from your #2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [Iggy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39072788/10907864)

I had this challenge when working on a **Rails 6** application with **Bootstrap 4**.

You **do not** need to add your **image directory** to the Rails assets path search in `config/initializers/assets.rb`

My **Image path** was `app/assets/images/products/product-16.jpg`.

That is the images were put in a `products` directory under the `images` directory.

I referenced it this way

```
<%= image_tag ('/assets/products/product-16.jpg'), class: 'product-image__img' %>
```

If you need to add a link to the image, then reference it this way:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('/assets/products/product-16.jpg'), 'http://#', target: '_blank', class: 'product-image__body' %>
```

This will result to this:

```
<a href="images/products/product-16.jpg" data-width="700" data-height="700" class="product-image__body" target="_blank">
</a>
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

put your image in public folder, my below image path is public/image_folder/img_name

```
<img src="<%= "/image_folder/img_name" %>">
```