# Need to display a logo on rails but still stuck on it, could you please give me some ideas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a very simple rails program and trying to display a logo by using this way, I made a folder named `courses` in folder `app\assets\images`, in that folder I had 4 images named 1 2 3 4 and then I tried to wrote this code in `app\views\courses\show.html.erb`

Here is my code

```
<%= image_tag "courses/#{@course.image}" %>
<div class="col m8">
<span class="card-title"><%= @course.title %></span> <p><%= @course.description %></p>
```

When I tried to access http://localhost:3000/courses/1 , they said to me that I had problem at

```
<%= image_tag "courses/#{@course.image}" %>
```

I still do not know why and very confusing because of this.
I am a newbie and could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: You've not put what error you're getting so I can't be sure, but try:
`<%= image_tag @course.image %>`

Comment: Do you have a "courses" controller ? I suggest you really do the getting started tutorial https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: What is your error?..

Comment: please refere this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069732/how-to-display-image-from-rails-local-project-folder

Answer (score 0):

You use as follow:

```
 <%= image_tag "sample_image.png" %>
```

for this your image should be in directory as

```
/assets/images/sample_image.png
```